# Perl - search and replace single master file to create multiple daughter files

Tags: perl, replace

I have a Master file from which I want to create several daughter files.  The master file has several lines of text in it which I wish to alter and then save to another file.  I wish to do this multiple times, each time saving the new file to a different filename.

For example my Master file has some REPLACETEXT which I wish to change to NEWTEXT and save the entire file into NEWTEXT1.txt. I then want to repeat this for NEWTEXT2 and save to NEWTEXT2.txt.  Again rinse and repeat another 100 or so times.

I assume there is a quick way with perl and loops but it has defeated my limited knowledge.

Comment: You should post the code for your error, not ask people to write code for you.  Please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: The problem is I cannot get started on the code and was looking for some pointers to it. I can do a one line perl -pe 's/old/new/g;' master.txt > newtext.txt type of thing but have no idea how to implement this into a script to loop it for multiple output files.  As I stated I am very new to perl and was just after some help.

Comment: It sounds like you need a basic introduction to the Perl language, and Stack Overflow isn't the place to look for that. Google will turn up several useful sites, such as this [Beginner's Introduction to Perl](http://www.perl.com/pub/2000/10/begperl1.html) on perl.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others suggested it is highly recommended to go through some basic Perl training.

This trivial code should work however

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my @keywords=('NEWTEXT1','NEWTEXT2','NEWTEXT2');
open(FILE,"Master.txt");
foreach (@keywords)
{
    open(NEWFILE,">$_.txt");
    seek (FILE, 0, 0);
    foreach $line (<FILE>)
    {
         $line=~s/REPLACETEXT/$_/g;
         printf NEWFILE ("$line");
    }
    close(NEWFILE);
}
close(FILE);
```